# Howler JS 2.0 - sound is not playing on cordova, android, device

Tags: android, cordova, audio, howler.js

i'm trying to play sound in mobile hybrid app (cordova, ionic, howlerJS v 2), https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/tree/2.0

By this way:

```
$scope.playSelectedItem = function(index) {
            try {
                var fileName = $scope.selectedSounds[index].file;
                var filePath  = "sounds/" +fileName+".mp3";
                console.log(filePath);
                var sound = new Howl({
                    src: [filePath]
                });

                sound.play();

            } catch(e) {
                $scope.showAlert();
            }
        };
```

In Chrome mobile emulator everything works fine, but on device is sound not playing.
I checked app permissions in manifest.xml and for sound playing is not required any special permissions.

What i'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Media Plugin offered by Cordova :

```
my_media = new Media('/android_asset/www/sound.mp3',
                // success callback
                function() {
                    WL.Logger.debug("playAudio():Audio Success");
                },
                // error callback
                function(err) {
                    WL.Logger.debug("playAudio():Audio Error: " + JSON.stringify(err));
                });

                // Play audio
                my_media.play();
```

Make sure to add '/android_asset' and then your path to the sound file. Android needs a absolute path to find the file and play it.

Comment: You've offered an alternative... but did not answer the question

Comment: you're mistaken in the sound file path, in android you should do this "/android_asset/www/sound.mp3"