# howler.js not working in Android 4.4.4 native browser

Tags: html5-audio, android-4.4-kitkat, howler.js

I am using howler.js for playing audio in one of my project, I am able to play audio file using howler.js in android native browser for first time. After page refresh audio does not play.

But works fine in google chrome after page refresh also. Any one else faced this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Below is the howler.js script I am using:

customSound = new Howl({
                        urls: [ urlSound ],
                        format: 'mp3',
                        buffer: false,
                        autoplay: true
                    });

Answer (score 0):

Try to refer t this answer, it solves your problem in a different way:

[Media Plugin offered by Cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28581423/1263588)

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am trying to play absolute mp3 file on page load. Cordova allows absolute mp3 path ?

Comment: yes it allows so, but you have to specify the URI type, for example : http:// or file://